# Just find number of its roots: $\sin{x}-x\cos{x}=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots

There is an other equation here:
$$\sin{x}-x\cos{x}=0$$
Range for x : $[0,\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

Now we want to write the equation $f(x)$ like $h(x)=g(x)$ :
$$\sin{x}=x\cos{x}$$
It is in a way that we know how to draw h and g functions diagram.
Then we draw the $h$ and $g$ function diagrams and find the common points of them. So it will be number of the $f(x)$ roots that here is the equation mentioned top.
Actually now my problem is with drawing the first equation's diagram
I want you to draw its diagrams step by step. Please help me with it!
Just help me drawing them.

Comment: there're actually infinitely many

Answer (score 1):

From $f(x):=\sin x- x\cos x$ we compute $f'(x)=x\sin x$. This shows that $f$ is strictly increasing for $0\leq x\leq \pi$ and strictly decreasing for $\pi\leq x\leq{3\pi\over2}$. As
$f(0)=0$, $f(\pi)=1$, and $f\bigl({3\pi\over2}\bigr)=-1$ we can conclude that there are exactly $2$ roots in the interval $\bigl[0,{3\pi\over2}\bigr]$, namely $0$ and a single root in $\>\bigl]\pi,{3\pi\over2}\bigr[\>$.

A "diagram" can only visualize what is written here, but cannot be considered as a proof per se. (There is no ISO-certificate for diagrams.)